Partial derivative of Mean Squared Error (MSE) in matrix notation
I recently read a chapter from a Machine Learning book where the Mean Squared Error (MSE) loss function was "minimized" using gradient descent. I'm trying to understand how to compute the partial derivative of the MSE, expressed in matrix notation, with respect to a vector $\mathbf{w}$.
$$
\begin{equation*}
 \mathrm{MSE} = \frac{1}{N} (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{Xw})^\top(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{Xw}).
\end{equation*}
$$
I assume that $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times1}$, $\mathbf{w} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times1}$ and $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$.
Following an article on Medium, I manage to take the following, tentative steps by applying the product rule, but I don't know how to move forward:
$$
\begin{align}
 & \frac{\partial \mathrm{MSE}}{\partial \mathbf{w}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{w}} \frac{1}{N} (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{Xw})^\top(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{Xw}) = \\
 & = \frac{1}{N} \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{w}} (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{Xw})^\top(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{Xw}) = \\
 & = \frac{1}{N} \left [-\mathbf{X}^\top(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{Xw}) + (\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{Xw})^\top (-\mathbf{X}) \right ] \\
 & = \frac{1}{N} \left [-\mathbf{Xy}^\top + \mathbf{X^\top Xw} \dots \right ] \\
\end{align}
$$
At this point I get lost and face two issues:

how do I compute this product $(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{Xw})^\top (-\mathbf{X})$? In the article it turns into $-\mathbf{yX} + \mathbf{Xw^\top X}$, but it doesn't look right;
after solving the first issue, how do I combine together the different "terms" of the resulting expression to get to the final result?

Just as a disclaimer, my background is in Linguistics and I've got a very limited mathematical background, so if you decide to spend a few moments to help I'd really appreciate it if you could explain your reasoning in simple terms.
